# Poner las series de barras de gráfico una debajo de la otra

Tags: highcharts

Quiero mostrar las series una debajo de la otra porque necesito comparar por tiempo en el eje x, es decir, una serie con múltiples datos y otra serie debajo.

Ejemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/jmsalai/nbyjsq5e/5/

Tendría que aparecer la serie 1 toda junta con 3 barras, luego la serie 2 con 2 barras y finalmente la serie 3 con 4 barras.

Una serie debajo de la otra, NO intercaladas

Me puede ayudar alguien, por favor

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a SO **en español!**  Por favor traduce tu pregunta. No se aceptan preguntas en otros idiomas, lo siento. En caso contrario la pregunta será cerrada y/o puede recibir votos negativos. Gracias

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow in Spanish @jmsalai, pleas translate your question to spanish.

Comment: Para cada serie es necesario que indiques los 4 valores, independientemente de si los valores son 0 o no

Comment: [es.so] te da la facilidad de crear un [repro] como _snippet_ en la pregunta (pulsa en el botón que indica `<>`). Por lo tanto, pon el código _en la pregunta_.

Comment: Más bien, puedes [edit]  tu pregunta y poner un ejemplo mínimo como te indicaron en otro comentario, para que recibas mejores respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Por definición una serie son un conjunto de datos a distribuir en, por ejemplo, varios periodos de tiempo.
Lo que podrías hacer es aglutinar los valores de cada serie en los diferentes arrays de datos, de tal forma que en los tres arrays que tienes, el primer valor sea el que quieres mostrar en la primera serie...

Ejemplo:

```javascript
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Serie1', 'Serie2', 'Serie3']
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Datos 1',
        data: [1, 4, 7]
    }, {
        name: 'Datos 2',
        data: [2, 5, 8]
    }, {
        name: 'Datos 3',
        data: [3, 6, 9]
    }]
});
```

En este caso la Serie 1 tendría los valores [1,2,3], la Serie 2 tendría [3,4,5]...

Espero que este "apaño" te sirva.

Comment: Gracias Óscar pero este seria el típico ejemplo de barras, lo que necesito es poder mostrar la serie 1, despúes la serie 2, etz. No mostrarlas mezclando los valores de cada serie.